# Moving a sprite in the direction it is facing, why does my attempt not work?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, monogame

I am using MonoGame to develop a Windows 8 store app/game (not for phone). I am also using the project with XAML, however this problem is not XAML related.

I am trying to get a ship to move in the direction it is facing, and the direction can be changed by pressing left and right keys to rotate the ship. The upwards key is used to move the ship in the direction it is facing.

The ship's image/texture is initially faced downwards(imagine an arrow facing downwards) when the game starts, so when I press the up key I want to move it downwards, however it moves to the right. I have gathered this is something to do with the rotation?

I have googled how to solve my problem and tried various methods, and this is my best attempt, however it does not work.

My parent sprite class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ship_Meteor_Game_V1
{
    abstract class cSprite
    {
        #region Properties
        Texture2D spriteTexture;
        Rectangle spriteRectangle;
        Vector2 spritePosition;

        public Texture2D SpriteTexture { get { return spriteTexture; } set { spriteTexture = value; } }
        public Rectangle SpriteRectangle { get { return spriteRectangle; } set { spriteRectangle = value; } }
        public Vector2 SpritePosition { get { return spritePosition; } set { spritePosition = value; } }
        #endregion

        abstract public void Update(GameTime gameTime);

        abstract public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch);

    }
}
```

My player class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ship_Meteor_Game_V1
{
    class cPlayer : cSprite
    {
        Vector2 origin;
        float rotation;
        float speed;

        public cPlayer()
        {
        }

        public cPlayer(Texture2D newTexture2D, Vector2 newPosition)
        {
            SpriteTexture = newTexture2D;
            SpritePosition = newPosition;
            speed = 2;
            rotation = 0;
        }
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                rotation = rotation + 0.1f;
            }

            if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                rotation = rotation - 0.1f;
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                Move();
            }
        }

        public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(SpriteTexture, SpritePosition, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, 0.2f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        }
        public void Move()
        {
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2( (float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation));
            direction.Normalize();
            SpritePosition = SpritePosition + (direction * speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want a ship to move in the direction it is facing but instead it is constantly moving sideways in whatever direction it is facing and I have no clue how to solve it. I can show you any extra classes/code you want if I have it.

PS: Anyone know a variable/type that can accept both mouse and keyboard input?

Answer (score 2):

Can't see anything obvious wrong with that code.

A guess would be you're using a ship graphic in your content manager that isn't facing upwards.

If that's the case you'll have to rotate it in an image editor, or modify your starting rotation.

My bet would be it's facing right, which would be an understandable confusion as in regular maths for radians 0 would be facing right.  In Xna however 0 is up.